# You have already deleted 5 of your own posts today; further deletes are blocked

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-answers, rate-limiting

I can't delete more than 5 of my own posts in a single day. Is this a bug, or intended behavior? I'm trying to clean up old, crappy posts of mine.

[image: let me delete]

Similar-looking problem, but it claims to be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed): https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81434/

Comment: I think things have changed since that question was posted.

Comment: Some details about the auto-flagging in [Slight modification to the “suspected vandalism” algorithm](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82884/slight-modification-to-the-suspected-vandalism-algorithm).

Comment: that link broken

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is an abuse-prevention mechanism used to stop users from maliciously destroying a lot of their content in a short period of time and denying users access to it. It's intended behavior. Perhaps a bit over-eager in that department, but it's probably wiser to err on the side of caution for that.

There are some exceptions to this limit - see the section *Deleting* in the answer to [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide).

Comment: Can/should I flag the rest of the answers I want to delete, or do I just have to keep at this for (# answers to delete)/5 days?

Comment: Well, Matt, first I believe you're delete-blocked for the next week ♪ But past that, yes, it would probably be wiser to take a slower pace. You *could* flag for assistance, but if you have a huge backlog of things to be deleted, then it's probably a lot of ancient stuff that isn't going to be looked at any time soon, so there's no real need to rush.

Comment: Delete blocked for the next _week_? ***!@#$*%^&**

Comment: @MattBall Why must you delete so much stuff? I think I have something like 8 deleted posts on all of SEI.

Comment: @drachenstern: because a lot of my old answers are absolute rubbish.

Comment: @MattBall and so while you recognize that you didn't know enough back then to be useful, now the answer is to remove them instead of making them better? :\ I don't think that's the right approach ...

Comment: @drach: okay, take [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300781/vs2005-website-project-problem/1300845#1300845) as an example. I was just starting out with ASP.NET, had _no idea_ what I was talking about, and I still don't. The OP's problem is long since solved, and my answer is nothing but dead weight.

Comment: @MattBall Well if you didn't know then and still don't ... I suppose that's acceptable eh?

Comment: @drach: good, now I can delete that one, too :)

Comment: @Blocked for the week after 5 deletes? Seriously? That's just going way to far.

Comment: Too far indeed. I got blocked just after deleting 5 useless posts. This is smelling like a tyranny to me.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to dig this one up again as well. Maybe allow us to delete posts with 0 upvotes? This should indicate that it's not a helpful answer and thus the loss isn't great. I, too, have a bunch of answers that are of poor quality.

Comment: I'll see about what we can do about possibly lightening the load without harming its intent.