# Higher own answer deletion limit for zero or negative score answers

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please allow us to delete our old, subpar, unvoted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98746/please-allow-us-to-delete-our-old-subpar-unvoted-answers)

I started cleaning up some of my old answers that are bad or that have the same information that's present in the accepted / higher scoring answer, and I hit this: [You have already deleted 5 of your own posts today; further deletes are blocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85523/you-have-already-deleted-5-of-your-own-posts-today-further-deletes-are-blocked)

So I can't delete more than 5 posts a day. That limit makes sense for protecting good answers, but I am mainly deleting answers with zero or negative score. They are most likely not good enough.

How about increasing the limit to 20 zero-or-negative answers? (and 5, or even less with 1+ score)

You can also limit that based on the total number of answers. If a person with 30 answers tries to delete half his answers, something's wrong. But if someone with 4500 tries to delete 20 of his oldest answers - that's probably fine.

Comment: Well, that's what you get for leaving bad answers in the first place!

Comment: Seriously, though, are you really sure these are worth deleting? Negative-scored answers I can understand, but answers with a score of zero don't necessarily have an information content of zero.

Comment: @camccann be sure that I am assessing them very critically. I had to go through 3 pages of 0-scoring answers to delete 5.

Comment: Okay, I can buy that. I looked through a random assortment and most of your zero-score answers seemed to have low views and be informational but not quite what the questioner wanted.

Comment: yes, I leave those in place. But look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866921/how-to-query-google-through-desktop-java-app/1866943#1866943 for example - it gives 1 link that is invalid.

Comment: @Bozho: Flag such answers with an explanation and a mod will delete them.

Comment: For what it's worth, I flagged that particular answer about an hour ago with the following explanation: "No actual content, only contains a rotted link that no longer points to anything useful, author of post agrees that it's worthless (see: [link to this meta question] )". Figured a demonstration would be most effective. ;]

Comment: @camcann: The average handling time for flags on SO is currently about an hour and a half.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: I wasn't implying I expected a faster response, if that's what you mean. Just trying to give Bozho more context.

Comment: Everything is rate-limited on Stack Overflow. This particular rate limit is to prevent massive damage from rage-quitting users deleting their own posts.

Comment: I find it unlikely that a user with 100k+ rep would rage-quit :)

Comment: @Bozho: Of course, it [sometimes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61077/162705) [happens](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95313/162705).

Comment: @Bozho I wouldn't be so sure of that myself

Comment: FYI: out of 8 flagged posts only one was deleted. Might be because it's Saturday, but still.