# Ease Community♦ flag for "multiple deletions in a short time" requirements

Tags: feature-request, flags, community-user

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Slight modification to the “suspected vandalism” algorithm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82884/slight-modification-to-the-suspected-vandalism-algorithm)

I think that Community♦ can be made a little smarter when offering up a flag with the reason of:

> Possible vandalism of own posts; multiple deletions in a short time;

There is [discussion around the handling of this flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94421/how-to-best-handle-the-possible-vandalism-of-own-posts-flag), from which the [following is gleaned (from Jeff no less)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94423/140951):

- Contact the user
- Indicate that they are removing valuable contributions to the community

However, when a user goes through and say, "cleans out the attic", I think that Community♦ shouldn't be so quick to flag.

That said, I propose the following:

Community♦ should *not* flag with the "Possible vandalism of own posts; multiple deletions in a short time;" if the following conditions are met:

- The posts deleted in question have net votes less than or equal to zero
- The posts deleted in question have exceeded a certain age

I'm not completely beholden to the second point, but I think that a user cleaning up their contributions *is a good thing* and we can reduce noise generated by good users doing good things.