# Allow moderators to see delete/undelete activity on users' profiles

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, undelete, self-delete

We get auto flags for 'possible vandalism' related to deletes, and these can be helpful at times in finding 'rage quit' users, or other potential problems.

But often, I would like to know if there is a prior pattern with the user doing this. While we can see posts of theirs which have been flagged, and perhaps find previous auto flags this way, it would be nice to see an overall view of their self-deletions and undeletions; mostly just to identify patterns.

Such a feature would be nice if it was *activity centered*, rather than post-centered. That is; each delete/undelete action should be shown. So we could easily see, for example, if someone went back-and-forth on a single post.  The "activity" tab in the profile would be a logical place to show these events.

I think this would be best to be limited to instant self-deletions, not deletion votes.

Comment: See my earlier request - [Improvements to the "possible vandalism - deletions" flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192417/improvements-to-the-possible-vandalism-deletions-flag) - which asks for different information but for the same reasons.

Comment: @ChrisF Oooh... good one. I *really* need to peruse the Feature Request tag more often! heh

Comment: Same request with somewhat different motivation behind it (in particular, that one didn't involve any flags): [Moderators should be able to see deleted posts in the Activity tab on a user's profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231258/162102)